# Eliminar con Inner Join SQL

Tags: sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
 Begin tran
 DECLARE @DATE DATETIME
SET @DATE = '2016/12/31 23:59:59'
 Delete From S
 From Solicitud S
 INNER Join EntradaVTP Vtp on S.Id = VTP.Id and S.FechaCreacion <= @DATE
Select * from EntradaVTP
rollback tran
```

Y el problema que tengo es que me dice que no puedo por Foreign Keys.. pero debería de poder solo que creo que hago mal la consulta.

Tengo la tabla Solicitud y la Tabla EntradaVTP

Necesito borrar de la tabla EntradaVTP todas las lineas que tengan el mismo ID y fecha inferior al 2016 de la tabla Solicitud. Es decir la Tabla Solicitud tiene dos campos ( Fecha e id ) Y quiero borrar de la entradaVTP todos los ID que sean inferiores al 2016. Pero para eso necesito sacarlos de Solicitud.

¿Qué hago mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No he entendido bien la consulta que realizas, pero la siguiente debe funcionar sin problemas. Lo que hace es borrar todos los registros de la tabla *EntradaVTP* cuyo *id* coincida con el *id* de la tabla *Solicitud* y que el año de creación sea inferior a 2016.

```
DELETE FROM EntradaVTP 
WHERE id in (
    SELECT id
    FROM Solicitud 
    WHERE YEAR(FechaCreacion) < 2016
)
```

Comment: gracias! Me complique mucho por lo que veo!! xD